# image.show() method gives permission error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am running through the facial_recognition library tests. In it I construct a `PIL.Image.Image` object from a numpy array. I then attempt to open that image.

I am using the Spyder IDE on macOS Mojave. I run Spyder by running `sudo spyder` from the terminal.

```
import face_recognition
from PIL import Image

image = face_recognition.load_image_file('test_images/biden.jpg')

face_locs = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

for loc in face_locs:
    top, right, bottom, left = loc

    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
    pil_image.show()
```

Upon reaching `pil_image.show()`, Preview opens and tries to open the image, but then displays the following error message in a window:

The file “tmp_pycgvqc.PNG” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

When I use the `pil_image.save()` method to save the image, and then I try open it, it works fine. Only using the `pil_image.show()` method produces the error.

Comment: Why are you running with `sudo`?

Comment: Two reasons (1) every time I see the word "permission" in an error I retry with sudo, (2) running Spyder with sudo allows me to send and receive packets in the IPython console